# mysql docker container not created after following instructions

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to create a mysql container using the directions [here to no](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) avail.  When running `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mysql:tag` it says `Unable to find image 'mysql:tag' locally`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the "tag" in mysql:tag with any of these:

- 8.0.21, 8.0, 8, latest
- 5.7.31, 5.7, 5
- 5.6.49, 5.6

like:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mysql:latest
```